# Is this a squircle (superellipse)? + Recursively mapping coordinates of a periodic function onto a 2D shape

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

If you take a $sin$ function and use it as the "x" coordinates in a cartesian plane, and you use an out-of-phase $sin$ function for "y" coordinates, you will obviously get the unit circle as shape, if you use $\pi/2$ as the phase for the y-coordinate.

I was playing around with the "wave" function that maps to the shape of a circle, rather than a $sin$ wave (meaning, it has a discontinuous first derivative), and looked what came out of that, instead of the circle coming out of the $sin$ wave.

[image: Notebook snippet]

I have three questions:

- Is this a squircle (superellipse)? As per first definition of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squircle.html
- How is this way of constructing 2D shapes called so I can learn more about them?
- If you are interested, I am mostly interested in doing this **recursively**. Meaning, in this case I would take the squircle shape, create a wave from it, and again create a shape, and keep doing this.. Is there any knowledge about this field?

Comment: ["squircle" is a little ambiguous.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle) Do you mean "superellipse" or something else? ... Also, can you describe your construction more mathematically? Code can be tricky to decipher.

Comment: Thanks @Blue I resolved the ambiguity by referring to Mathworld

Comment: @Blue: I think $y:\mathbb R\to[-1,1]$ is a periodic function whose graph consists of semicircles, like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1019005/, and the final shape is the parametric curve whose horizontal and vertical coordinates are given by $y$ a quarter-period out of phase. buddhabrot, can you confirm?

Comment: That is correct @Blue

Comment: Then the curve in the first quadrant is given by $x=\sqrt{1-t^2}, y=\sqrt{1-(1-t)^2}$ for $t\in[0,1]$. We have $x^4+y^4=(1-t^2)^2+(1-(1-t)^2)^2\ne\mathrm{const}$, so the curve is *not* a squircle. However $x^4+y^4$ only varies by $12.5\%$ over this range, which explains why it looks so much like a squircle.

Comment: Does this curve have a name?

Comment: "How is this way of constructing 2D shapes called so I can learn more about them?" 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation. "Does this curve have a name?" Not that I know of, but it is an example of a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_plane_curve.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Yes of course, parametric curves. I guess in this case the circle is the parametric curve of the sine function, and this Quartic plane curve is then the parametric curve of the semi circle shape. I’m curious if this recursion can be modelled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us focus on the first quadrant, in which the analogue of $\cos$ is $x=\sqrt{1-t^2}$ for $t\in[0,1]$, and the analogue of $\sin$ is $y=\sqrt{1-(1-t)^2}$. For it to be a squircle, we would need $x^4+y^4=\mathrm{const}$, but one can check that this does not hold for the given curve.

However, expressing $t$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, we have
$$
t=\sqrt{1-x^2}, \\
1-t=\sqrt{1-y^2},
$$
so the implicit equation of the curve, at least in the first quadrant, is
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=1.$$
It turns out that this equation also works in the other quadrants too.

The implicit equation can be expanded to the equivalent form
$$x^4 + y^4 - 2(1 - x^2)(1 - y^2) = 1.$$
Here the difference with the squircle equation $x^4+y^4=1$ is clear.