# A graph made of half circles

Tags: real-analysis, functions, graphing-functions, elementary-functions

Taking inspiration from the question [What kind of curve is made of half circles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019005/what-kind-of-curve-is-made-of-half-circles) I'm trying to build up a function $f$ whose graph is similar to a sine function made of semicircles. While finding an expression for the absolute value of this function is not so difficult and the formula looks like

$$
|f(x)|=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\pi(x-1)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}}{\pi}\right)^2}
$$

an explicit formula for the original problem seems way more involved. I'm searching for a formula that have the following properties:

1. No functions defined by cases.
2. Domain of $f$ has to be $\mathbb{R}$ so if possible no tricks with the sign function.
3. The expression should involve only elementary functions and their inverses (No special functions, series or something more involved) since it has to be understandable with a minimum analysis background.

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.